# Are there any other neuter words of the second declension that end on -us than "virus"?

Tags: declension, morphology, ending, neuter, second-declension

*Virus* is a neuter word of the second declension even though it ends on *-us*, as evidenced by its genitive on *-i* (it has no plural). Are there any other such words?

Bonus question: is it possible that there were two forms of *virus*, one masculine on *-us*, the other neuter on *-um*, that were later conflated into one word? Their origin might then be adjectival.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tuomo Pekkanen's *Ars Grammatica* (a Latin grammar in Finnish) says that the second declension has three neuters ending in *-us*: *vīrus*, *vulgus* and *pelagus*.
They are only used in the singular, and accusative is exactly like the nominative (not *-um*).

I have no clue about the origin of these words.
I'm not sure if these words even have a similar history.

Comment: *Pelagus* is a Greek borrowing (τὸ πέλαγος, -εος) which retained its neuter gender; the Greek nom./acc. plural *pelage* does occur. *Vulgus* and *virus* are probably (thus Weiss) each a conflation of two nouns, a masculine and a neuter from the same stem and with the same meaning: in the case of *vulgus*, probably an s-stem neuter and an o-stem masculine; in that of *virus*, probably both o-stems (cognates: Gk. ἰός m., Ved. viṣam n.). Acc. *vulgum* occurs rarely.

Comment: @TKR, thanks! I asked [a separate question](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1122/79) about the plurals. You can answer about the plural declension of *pelagus* there if you want. You should also consider turning your comment into another answer here, but it's your call.

Comment: There's also *cetus*, which is another word from Greek (where it's neuter); my understanding is that the OLD calls it masculine in the singular and neuter in the plural (*cete*) but I don't have my OLD near me now to check.

Comment: @JoelDerfner: Cf. *locus*, sometimes plural *loca*.

Comment: @Cerberus, masculine and neuter plurals of *locus* have a different meaning.