# What is the plural of virus, vulgus and pelagus?

Tags: declension, morphology, plural, second-declension

There are three neuters in the second declension ending in *-us*: *virus*, *vulgus* and *pelagus*.
(See [this previous question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1117/79) for origin and listing of such words.)
My grammar tells me that these words are not used in the plural at all.
I cannot believe that no one would have used these words in the plural through the millennia of Latin.
If I want to scan my computer for viruses, describe how globalization brings the masses of different areas closer together, or sail the seven seas, I could use some plurals.

What are the plural forms of these three words?
Are they found in all cases?
Are they declined in the same way?

Neuters ending in *-us* typically have plurals *-ora* or *-era* (e.g. *tempus–tempora* and *vulnus–vulneris*).
But these are in third declension and the *-s* is part of the stem.
For my three words *-s* is (a part of?) the nominative case ending and they follow the second declension.
Therefore the most appealing plural endings are *-a*, *-orum* and *-is*, but I have not seen these mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Since they're traditionally regarded as second-declension neuters, they would be *vira, vulga,* and *pelaga*; but their meanings don't really lend themselves to plurality, and there are other words that fill those voids.

Comment: @Anonym, why do the meanings not allow plurality?

Comment: Because they're mass nouns. *Pelagus amo* means 'I love the sea (in general)', whereas *mare amo* means 'I love a certain sea/the specified sea'

Comment: @Anonym, mass nouns can be pluralized, although it is not very common. See TKR's answer for an attested example of a plural of *pelagus*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Acc. pl. *pelagē* occurs in Lucretius, *De Rerum Natura* 6.619:

> at pelage multa et late substrata videmus

This is simply the Greek plural: the word is a loan of Greek πέλαγος, whose nom./acc. pl. is πελάγη.

A [Packard](http://latin.packhum.org/search) search finds no results for *vira, virora, vulga, vulgora*.

Comment: Looking up the context of that line led me to ask [this question](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1149/118).

Answer (score 5):

It seems there are [many theories](http://www.ofb.net/~jlm/virus.html#ASM_Update), among them *viri*, *virora*, and *virus*. (The point of the article is that it's pointless to try to figure it out.)

Here, however, is a [refutation](http://interretialia.tumblr.com/post/58389248885/some-notes-on-the-inflection-of-the-latin-word) of the article linked above that contains an argument based on what seems to be solid linguistics ("seems" because it's been so long since I studied linguistics that I can't really tell anymore) and asserts that the plural has to be *vira*.

(Sorry about the other answer, which I've deleted—I forgot momentarily how to use a dictionary and was taking genitive as plural.)

Comment: That first article seems a bit silly to me. *Virus* does indeed look a bit like *vir* when declined, but the length of the *-i-* is different. And sometimes different words become the same when suitably declined. Declined forms are attested, so guessing whether it should be fourth or third declension has little support. The second article looks much more credible.

Comment: Yeah, that was my sense, too.