# Pes ultimus insanus cuiusdam versus Lucretii?

Tags: scansion, lucretius

How do you scan line 621 of *De Rerum Natura*, [book VI](https://books.google.com/books?id=bVoCAAAAQAAJ&lpg=PA207&ots=SSnqfECpZN&dq=at%20pelage%20multa%20et%20late%20substrata%20videmus&pg=PA207#v=onepage&q=proinde%20licet%20quamvis%20ex%20unoquoque%20loco%20sol&f=false), shown in bold below?

> Praeterea, magnam sol partem detrahit æstu.
>   Quippe videmus enim vestes humore madentes
>   Exsiccare suis radiis ardentibu’ solem.
>   At pelage multa et late substrata videmus.
>   **Proinde, licet quamvis ex unoquoque loco sol**
>   Humoris parvam delibet ab æquore partem;
>   Largiter in tanto spatio tamen auferet undis.

(My amateur translation: "Furthermore, the Sun draws off a large part of [the oceans' water] with its heat. Certainly we see that the Sun dries out clothes dripping with moisture with its fiery rays. And we see the many seas stretched out below [the Sun]. **So, however** small a part of the moisture **the Sun** takes from the sea **out of any one spot**, it still takes abundantly in such a space from the waves." I'm not sure of this translation; I've asked a question about it [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1150/118).)

If I assume that Lucretius is lengthening the first syllable of *proinde,* I get:

> Prōin/dē licet / quamvīs / ex ū/nōquoque / locō sōl

That last foot is crazy. It doesn't have anything like the cadence you normally get in hexameter. Is this just a flaw in Lucretius's verse, am I mis-scanning it, or is there some hexameter custom at work here that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last syllable in *proinde* is short but the first one is not split in two.
Correcting this makes the rest of the line scan naturally:

> Proindĕ, lĭ/cet quam/vīs ex / ūnō/quōquĕ lŏ/cō sōl

The caesura seems to take place between *quamvis* and *ex*.
I do not find a similarly suitable place for it in your scansion.
Having trouble placing the caesura is a good sign of wrong scansion.

Also notice that both 'O's in *unoquoque* are long — the ablative ending is needed for both *unus* and *quis* that together with the enclitic *-que* form the pronoun *unusquisque*.

Comment: Many thanks for the tip about the cæsura! I will keep that in mind the next time I come across one of these. About _proinde,_ is the first syllable made into a diphthong to save the meter, as if it were spelled _proende_?

Comment: @BenKovitz, I am not sure how *proinde* is pronounced in prose. It might be that it always has two syllables or that synizesis is used here. I wonder if there are examples where scansion forces *proinde* to have three syllables and which is more common in poetry. I can't judge by this one example.

Comment: Is there any agreement about the pronunciation of elided vowels? Pr[o]inde, may have been pronounced **preende,** or **prweende.** But it was scanned *long-short* either way.

Comment: @Hugh, I think 'oi' is a diphthong (by synizesis) rather than the 'o' being elided. (Although scansion does no rule out elision.) I don't quite understand what you mean by pronunciation of elided vowels. If you can elaborate, it might make a good separate question.