# How to decline a whale?

Tags: morphology, noun, gender, animals, plural

The Latin word [*cētus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcetus) (a whale or some other major sea creature) behaves peculiarly.
In singular it is a normal-looking masculine *cētus*, but in plural it is a neuter *cētē*.
The original Greek word is neuter in both numbers (κῆτος, κήτη).
This word came up in the search for [neuter animals in Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/13994/79).

How is the word *cētus* declined?
If it was reanalyzed as a second declension masculine in Latin, I can guess how the singular endings look like.
But how about plural?
The ending *-ē* is highly irregular for a plural neuter in Latin.
(The only other one I can think of is [*pelagē*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1122/79).)
The accusative is certainly like the nominative, and dative and ablative should be identical.
The question boils down to two forms:
**What are the plural genitive and plural dative/ablative forms of *cētus*?**

Going by the Latin second declension, *cētōrum* and *cētīs* sound likely.
But the Greek word seems to correspond better to the Latin third declension, so *cēt(i)um* and *cētibus* would make sense, too.
Greek style plural endings besides nominative and accusative seem very rare in Latin, but perhaps that could be possible, too.

If the forms are unattested, what should they be by reasonable analogy?
Whether or not perfectly justified classically, I would much like to be able to use all forms of the word.

Comment: A. Be polite but not overly apologetic in doing so.

Answer (score 8):

The attested nom. sing. is either the Latinised cetus m., or the borrowed cetos n. In the plural only the borrowed cete n., nom./acc. is attested, but by analogy one would expect gen. *ceton and dat. *cetesi. Which does leave us at a loss for the ablative.

Comment: Need I add that https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cetus , true to the principle that “fools rush in where angels fear to tread”, does not hesitate to invent a full plural paradigm ceti, cetorum, cetis, etc. All fake.

Comment: It appears that the plural *ceti* is in taxonomical use in some compounds. It's unfortunate but hardly surprising that the fake plurals are in use.

Comment: well, while the OLD entry confirms this, but take a look at some interesting data in the TLL entry http://publikationen.badw.de/en/thesaurus/lemmata#24838

Comment: @AlexB. Thank you for the information. It appears that ceti, cetorum, cetis, cetibus and acc. pl. cetos can be found here and there in post-classical (mainly Christian) authors.

Comment: as to be expected from post-classical authors. But in Classical Latin the paradigm was very defective - you're absolutely correct.

Comment: fdb: Pock. Ox. Lat. Dict. gives "cetus, i (m)" with no further qualification. Therefore, does Oxford agree with Wiki?

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: There appears to be an unholy alliance between Oxford & Wiki. I recall Russian word, KUT = whale. In Russian, foreign (non-Russian) words do not decline. Perhaps the Romans were not over-bothered about declining foreign words. However unlikely, this might explain the current confusion.

Comment: @tony from the OLD: "**cētus, ~os** m., neut. [Gk κῆτος] Forms and gender: In singular usu.  2nd decl. (m.); nom.neut. ~os Man. 1.433, ~us 5.15; acc. ~os Plin. *Nat*. 32.10; nom., acc. pl. ~ē (neut.). A large sea animal (whale, porpoise, or dolphin) or its flesh."

Comment: @tony not sure why you mentioned Russian кит - which has a regular paradigm in Russian btw (кита, киту, китом etc)

Comment: @Alex B: Thanks: Oxford did define as "whale" etc., I meant that nothing was given about any irregular, or otherwise, declension details--me being too terse. I enjoyed studying Russian at school, recalled some things, foreign words don't decline, which might be relevant, here?

Comment: @tony yes, I see your point now. Loanwords that haven't been fully assimilated do indeed quite often have irregular or incomplete paradigms.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly idle nonsense on my part but κῆτος behaves exactly like an s-stem like γένος, with an oblique stem *kētes-*, so if I were a moderately clever/insufferable Roman I'd decline it analogously:

|  | sg. | pl. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **nom./voc./acc.** | cētus | cētera |
| **gen.** | cēteris | cēterum |
| **dat.** | cēterī | cēteribus |
| **abl.** | cētere | cēteribus |

(This obviously risks confusion with the actual word *ceterum* in some cases.)

While this obviously didn't happen, Roman grammarians were sufficiently astute to notice the connection between γένος and *genus* even if they didn't fully understand it, so in principle it could have.

Comment: "I think that the Carthage of the whales should be destroyed."

Answer (score 2):

My copy of Stelten's *Dictionary of Ecclesiastical Latin* gives *cetion* for the genitive plural. Nothing about the ablative, or even dative, though.