# How did vulgus get its ending?

Tags: etymology, declension, neuter, second-declension

*Vulgus* "crowd, mob, common people" is a neuter second-declension noun. But unlike most second-declension neuters, it ends in *-us*, like a masculine.

How did this happen? Is there an etymological reason why *vulgus* got an *-us* ending while so many other neuters got *-um*?

Comment: see some comments here https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/are-there-any-other-neuter-words-of-the-second-declension-that-end-on-us-than

Answer (score 3):

There surely is an etymological reason, but unfortunately we don’t know it. Or there is no consensus about it.

All grammars mention the three second-declension neuters in *-us*, *pelagus, virus* and *vulgus*, and many go on explaining that *pelagus* is a recent Greek loanword which retained its gender (possibly influenced by *mare*), while *virus* has Indo-european cognates clarifying its history, and... what is said of *vulgus* is, at best, that both a regular masculine and a regular neuter exist alongside the irregular neuter in *-us*. They could be recent analogical forms, but somebody thinks that they are ancient and the irregular form was somehow conflated from them. *Vulgus* has known Indo-european cognates (Sanskrit *varga*, “group”), but they don’t explain its irregularity in an unambiguous way. At least, not in any sources I’ve consulted.